# Get size of execution queue for boost::asio::thread_pool

Tags: c++, threadpool, boost-asio

I am using the `boost::asio::thread_pool` in a multithread C++ program and I need to know how many tasks in the queue are currently executed to know if I can submit a new task or not.

```
// async thread, pass pool_ by ref
static void somecallback(boost::asio::thread_pool& pool) {
  if (pool.%queue_size% < %some limit%) {
    boost::asio::post(pool, my_task);
  }  else {
    std::cerr << "queue overflowed!" << std::endl;
  }
}

// main thread
class A {
 public:
   A():pool_(4){};
   ~A();
   // some logic
   ...
 private:
   boost::asio::thread_pool pool_;
}

A::~A(){
  pool_.join();
}
```

Is it possible to somehow get the logs of the `queue_size` parameter and its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature. Also, note that in the the Asio model there's no notion of "Task". The thread pool implementation isn't a general-purpose one, but it enriches an *execution context* with threads that run (intermediate handlers) for asynchronous operations.

Handlers `post`-ed directly to the pool 's executors are only a small part of the ecosystem and typical load for an execution context.

Therefore it will make sense most to track "tasks" at the application level, e.g. using an atomic shared counter that is incremented/decremented at task start/exit.

As a simple example

**Live On Coliru**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

static std::atomic_int tid_gen{};
thread_local int const tid = tid_gen++;

namespace task_counter {
    static std::atomic_uint s_pending{};

    struct guard {
        guard()            noexcept { ++s_pending; }
        ~guard()           noexcept { if (armed_) --s_pending; }
        guard(guard&& rhs) noexcept : armed_(std::exchange(rhs.armed_, false)) {}
        guard& operator=(guard&& rhs) { std::swap(armed_, rhs.armed_); return *this; }

        unsigned current() const { return s_pending; }
      private:
        bool armed_ = true;
    };
}

auto make_task(char const* id) {
    return [=, g=task_counter::guard{}] { //
        printf("t:%d\ttask:%s\tpending:%i\n", tid, id, g.current());
    };
}

int main(){
    {
        boost::asio::thread_pool p{8};
        printf("t:%d\ttask:%s\tpending:%i\n", tid, __FUNCTION__, task_counter::s_pending.load());

        auto ex = p.get_executor();
        for (auto av : {"foo", "bar", "qux", "quux", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", //
                "sbb", "one", "dhk", "dhhk", "pbetr", "tenhyg", "tnecyl", "jnyqb"})
            post(ex, make_task(av));

        p.join();
    }
    assert(!task_counter::s_pending);
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
t:0 task:main   pending:0
t:1 task:foo    pending:4
t:1 task:quux   pending:4
t:2 task:bar    pending:4
t:3 task:qux    pending:3
t:1 task:corge  pending:2
t:4 task:grault pending:1
t:4 task:garply pending:1
t:5 task:waldo  pending:1
t:3 task:sbb    pending:4
t:3 task:dhk    pending:4
t:3 task:dhhk   pending:3
t:6 task:one    pending:4
t:3 task:tenhyg pending:3
t:3 task:tnecyl pending:2
t:4 task:pbetr  pending:3
t:7 task:jnyqb  pending:1
```